# rails postgres some of the sequence not start from 1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I am using ruby on rails with postgresql database. A weird thing happened that some of the tables_id_seq are not starting from 1, but 980190963. But some of the seq are correctly starting from 1.

The problem is when I tried to insert data into those table which seq not start from 1, unique primary key violation raised occasionally.

--EDIT--

I found that when I do

```
rake db:migrate test
```

The problem happens.

If I do

```
rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=test
```

The problem has gone.

Comment: is there data in those tables you can't afford to lose?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to keep the data in those tables, you can run the following which will reset the table (THIS WILL REMOVE ANY DATA THERE) and restart the tables id to start at 1.  THIS IS ONLY VIABLE IF YOU DON"T NEED THE DATA IN THAT TABLE!

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("TRUNCATE TABLE table_name_here RESTART IDENTITY")
```

As far as why your tables are starting at that id value I would start by checking your migrations.  Maybe somewhere in the code there is an "Alter Sequence" sql statement but again not sure.